# What about adding DevOps SE to the migration menu?

Tags: discussion

Currently, it is not possible to move a question to the [DevOps SE](https://devops.stackexchange.com/):

[image]

If a question is about tools that are related to "how to improve the communication between Dev and Ops", like Jenkins, Cloud automation.

What does the ServerFault (SF) community think about this proposal?

I personally think that questions about docker, k8s, jenkins, gitlab should be posted on DevOps as these destroy the wall of confusion, e.g. developers can create their own docker images rather than asking Ops whether they can create a VM for them.

**Discussion**

- https://meta.serverfault.com/a/7910/215599
- [Why the hostility?](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/5337/215599)
- [Why the hostility?](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/5337/215599)
- [How do you ask a question about server fault after reading the faq and not finding clarification?](https://meta.serverfault.com/q/953/215599)

Comment: I'm confused by the juxtaposition of your opening sentence with the screenshot.  Do you want DevOps added to the list of generally-available migration targets, which is what your title requests, or to the linked-to sites in the description of the fourth OT close reason (as suggested by your screenshot)?

Comment: Last time I looked the migration target list was full. I don't think it's possible to set a beta site as a migration target in the close dialog anyway. But moderators can still manually migrate questions to beta sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The devops site is still in beta, so by the company's rules it is not possible to add it to a migration list. The reasoning for this is that sites have to be able to stand on their own and pull in their own audience without relying on network migrations.

Further, I don't think there are sufficient people here who are motivated to do any migrations (anywhere) there were just 32 (away) in the last 90 days.

Personally I'm disappointed that the devops.se site has not taken off as I was hoping it would take away all the crappy questions away from SF.