# Merge DevOps into ServerFault? (polite for: close down DevOps SE and find the best SE for the freed Q/A?)

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

There are few questions from users >200 points on DevOps.

There are on the whole 5000 questions, and new questions get few views and few answers.

This SE should be merged into ServerFault even in cases where ServerFault does not fully fit as a name.

I thought using DevOps SE would be better for DevOps issues, but there are too many new users like me who do not know that this Stack Exchange is almost dead. They just go there, ask a question, and find out about it later. This waste of time should be avoided.

Comment: What does the guys at Devops SE say about this?

Comment: One of the founding reasons for a separate devops.se was that Serverfault was not a good fit for many of it's users and questions, This is still true. Closing it and merging it to SF will do no one a service. My comment [here](https://meta.serverfault.com/a/9587/9517) about devops.se remains true.

Comment: Here on SF there are also too many new users and too few answerers as well. More than 50% of questions [go unansered](https://data.stackexchange.com/serverfault/query/303570/answer-rate-over-time#graph) and the gap is growing.

Comment: @user9517 I agree, it does not at all fit to "ServerFault" in the core sense of the word in many cases. But where would it fit then? Super User?

Comment: As long as it's not here I don't care. I remain disappointed that the devops.se site has not taken off as I was hoping it would take away all the crappy questions away from SF.

Comment: @user9517 We talk about 5000 DevOps questions. SF has 310.000. Cannot be the life changer in any case, whatever your opinion is on this. If it is just to keep out crappy questions, I would rather question your point of view on it. For crappy questions, you have the vote button. This question here is not about improving the SF quality by keeping the DevOps questions out, but by looking *only* at the topic. And DevOps is kind of a duplicate of ServerFault in many cases, I know that from asking a few questions there and here myself, there is a confusion about ServerFault and DevOps.

Comment: I'm well aware of how the site is supposed to work, I'm still the second highest voter on hte site and I rarely contribute any more. The reason I rarely contribute is that wading through an amazonian sized river of crappy questions looking for something interesting (an voting appropriately along the way) is too wearing. Adding more crappy stuff from sites that failed to take off isn't going to help.

Comment: @user9517 Then new users should get informed that they should rather try it on ServerFault. So that DevOps can fade out. If you have such an experience there, your point of view on it is understandable. Perhaps DevOps needs to be stopped so that the Q/A are archived for research and asking questions is not possible anymore.

Comment: @I^H oops @user9517 Interesting that the decline in # of questions may have bottomed out but the answers continues to go down...

Comment: @Ward-ReinstateMonica And take away any self-answered question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When it comes to merging the topic into SF, it seems like an OK fit, but how SF feels about DevOps questions is not the main issue.

As was implied by a comment, this is probably something that would have to be driven by users on DevOps.SE  If the users there want to shut it down and merge it into another site, they would have to raise the issue on their meta and get SE involved.

Comment: I do not expect a large meta user community in a seemingly dead SE. There are to the largest part only new users with a few points, and those are the users I am asking for. They will not even look at the meta site.

Comment: Opened there. Let us see :))))))
https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/merge-devops-into-serverfault-polite-for-close-down-devops-se-and-find-the-be

Answer (score 1):

The core of the answer on [DevOps meta - "Merge DevOps into ServerFault? (polite for: close down DevOps SE and find the best SE for the freed Q/A?)"](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/merge-devops-into-serverfault-polite-for-close-down-devops-se-and-find-the-be):

> This stackexchange is not quite as dead as it would seem.

That alone says it all. There are still some happy people. And if that is true, the community there should not be left behind and get a further testing time and might also take the right turn.